# How to compare two different arrays which has different property names and remove unmatched ones in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I havve two different arrays with different property names like below

```js
arrayA = [
    { id: 20, name: 'Jason' },
    { id: 15, name: 'Harry' },
    { id: 5, name: 'Clara' },
    { id: 9, name: 'Melonie' }
]

arrayB = [
    { courseID: 12, studentID: 20 },
    { courseID: 12, studentID: 15 }
]
```

I want to compare these two different arrays and remove unmatched ids from `arrayA`. For comparison, `id` field of `arrayA` and `studentID` field of `arrayB` matters. if these fileds aren't equal to each other, they should be removed from `arrayA`.

Expected is below

```js
arrayA = [{id: 20, name: 'Jason' }, { id: 15, name: 'Harry' }]
```

Here is what I tried below but didn't work. Gave me empty array.

```js
filteredElements = this.arrayA.map(e => e.id).filter(
    val => this.arrayB.indexOf(val.studentID) !== -1
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that in following steps:

- Use `map()` on `arrayB` and create array of `courseID`.
- Then create a `Set()` from that `Array`
- Then use `filter()` `arrayA` and check whether `id` of object exists in above created `Set` or not using `Set.prototype.has()`

```js
const arrayA = [{id:20,name:'Jason'},{id:15,name:'Harry'},{id:5,name:'Clara'},{id:9,name:'Melonie'}]
const arrayB =[{courseID:12,studentID:20},{courseID:12,studentID:15}];
const ids = new Set(arrayB.map(x => x.studentID));
const res = arrayA.filter(x => ids.has(x.id));
console.log(res);
```

Comment: The above answer looks to be functionally correct.  Just noting that the `let ids = ...` should probably be a `const ids = ...` since not re-assigning `ids`.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let arrayA = [{id: 20,name: 'Jason'},{id: 15,name: 'Harry'},{id: 5,name: 'Clara'},{id: 9,name: 'Melonie'}]
let arrayB = [{courseID: 12,studentID: 20},{courseID: 12,studentID: 15}];
let filtered=arrayA.filter(obj =>{ if(arrayB.find(course => course.studentID == obj.id))return true;return false;
});
console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a dictionary from `courseMembers`, keyed on `studentID`, to enable O(1) lookup.

Filter `students` according to the dictionary.

```js
const students = [{id:20,name:'Jason'},{id:15,name:'Harry'},{id:5,name:'Clara'},{id:9,name:'Melonie'}]
const courseMembers = [{courseID:12,studentID:20},{courseID:12,studentID:15}]

function withCourses(students, courseMembers) {
    const map = courseMembers.reduce((acc, {studentID}) => 
        (acc[studentID] = true, acc), {})
    return students.filter(({id}) => map[id])
}
const result = withCourses(students, courseMembers)
console.log(result) // [{ id:20, name:"Jason" },{ id:15, name:"Harry" }]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var studentIds = arrayB.map(course => course.studentID);
var result = arrayA.filter(student => studentIds.includes(student.id));
```

The variable `result` contains your result.